# Kinetic energy of rigid bodies about the center of mass

Tags: energy, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, rotational-kinematics, rigid-body-dynamics

Suppose, we have some rigid body, that is rotating about some pivot. In this case, we can easily find the kinetic energy, by choosing a random point $P$ on the body. The kinetic energy of the body ( irrespective of the origin ) is given by the sum of the kinetic energy of this point $P$, and the rotational kinetic energy about this point $P$.

We choose this point $P$ to be the center of mass. In fact, if we choose any other point, we'd indirectly be using the center of mass frame in some way or the other, like finding the moment of inertia about this point using the parallel axis theorem.

However, if the original axis of rotation passes through the center of mass, why can we not decompose this kinetic energy about some other point ?

For example, if a ring is rotating about some point on the circumference, we can write kinetic energy as the sum of kinetic energy of the COM $+$ the rotational kinetic energy about the COM. ( We can use some other point that is not the COM too ).

However, if the ring is rotating about the COM, why can we not write kinetic energy as the sum of kinetic energy of some random point and the rotational kinetic energy about the same point ?

( I know that we can't do it, just looking for a mathematical/intuitive reason as to why is it so ? ). The kinetic energy about an arbitrary point  can be broken into the kinetic energy of the COM and the kinetic energy about the COM. However, the opposite clearly seems to be incorrect.

Comment: I have never heard of this "random point selection". The total kinetic energy is the sum of kinetic energies of all of the points on the body. Do you have a reference, or can you clarify this method?

Comment: @BioPhysicist suppose I have a rod rotating about an end. I can choose any point on the rod. Using parallel axis theorem I can find MOI about that point, and since all points have same $\omega$, I can find the kinetic energy of that point itself. Summing these would give me the total KE. Normally, we select this point to be the COM. So we add the KE about the COM and the KE of the COM. Instead, I'm choosing some other point, for example, the point at a distance $l/3$ from the pivot. That is what I meant by choosing a point at random.